# Proving linear dependence of vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $V$ be the vector space $\mathbb{C}^3$ over $\mathbb{C}$, and consider the vectors $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ z_1 \\ z_1^2 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ z_2 \\ z_2^2 \end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ z_3 \\ z_3^2 \end{bmatrix}$. What restrictions on $z_1, z_2, z_3$ make these vectors linearly dependent?

My believe the answer is $z_1 = z_2 = z_3$, but I am having a hard time proving it. By taking arbitrary scalars $x$, $y$, $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and setting this equal to the zero vector, I got a system of equations:
\begin{align*}
x + y + z & = 0 \\
x z_1 + y z_2 + z z_3 & = 0 \\
x z_1^2 + y z_2^2 + z z_2^3 & = 0
\end{align*}
But I can't figure out how to continue from here.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $x,y,z$ not all 0, exist such that:

$$\begin{cases}
x + y + z & = & 0 & (1)\\
x z_1 + y z_2 + z z_3 & = &0 & (2)\\
x z_1^2 + y z_2^2 + z z_3^2 & =& 0 & (3)
\end{cases}$$

(we can assume without loss of generality that $x \ne 0$).

Let us show that this is possible iff "two at least of the $z_k$ are equal", not necessarily the three ones.

**1) Proof with determinants:** Indeed, the determinant of your system

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1\\
z_1&z_2&z_3\\
z_1^2&z_2^2&z_3^2
\end{vmatrix}=(z_2-z_1)(z_3-z_1)(z_3-z_2)$$

is zero iff two of the $z_k$ are equal [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

**2) Proof Without determinants:**

Considering that we are in the situation recaped at the beginning of this answer, let us reduce eliminate $z$ from the 3 variables system by extracting $z=-x-y$ from (1), and plugging it into (2) and (3):

$$\begin{cases}x(z_1-z_3)+y(z_2-z_3)&=&0\\x(z_1^2-z_3^2)+y(z_2^2-z_3^2)&=&0\end{cases}$$

This system can be written under the vector form:

$$x(z_1-z_3)\binom{1}{z_1+z_3}+y(z_2-z_3)\binom{1}{z_2+z_3}=\binom{0}{0}\tag{R}$$

Let us make a proof by contradiction: let us assume that none of the relationships $z_1=z_2, z_2=z_3,z_3=z_1$ exist. In such a case,  relationship (R) would imply the proportionnality

$$\binom{1}{z_1+z_3}=\underbrace{-\dfrac{y(z_2-z_3)}{x(z_1-z_3)}}_C\binom{1}{z_2+z_3}\tag{R'}$$

(remeber $x \ne 0$) (R') can happen if and only if the front coefficient $C$ is $1$ (in order the two first component $1$ and $1$ are equal!) but if such is the case,

$$\binom{1}{z_1+z_3}=\binom{1}{z_2+z_3}\tag{R''}$$

implying $z_1=z_2$ contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I haven't gotten to determinants yet, though, so I am trying to solve this without determinants. Is there a way to do it with just algebra?

Comment: Yes. I am going to write it as an Edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I've been unsuccessful at working out the algebra myself.

Comment: See as well what I have added at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful. If I can ask jut one more question: this proof establishes that at least one of the relations $z_1 = z_2$, $z_2 = z_3$,  or $z_3 = z_1$ hold. But how do we know that all three don't hold?

Comment: I haven't said that your initial guess (the case $z_1=z_2=z_3$) couldn't happen ; I just said that a sufficient condition was that **at least** two of them are equal for having dependance.

Comment: If my answer is satisfying for you with its two proofs, check it with the check sign (it will indicate to people wondering if something has still to be worked that it's completed).